# Specify location of bar on bar chart R

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have example data below:

```
> eg_data <- data.frame(period = c("1&2", "1&2","1", "1", "2","2"), size = c("big", "small", "big", "small","big", "small"), trip=c(1000, 250, 600, 100, 400, 150))
```

I want to make a stacked bar chart, where I have both periods as the first bar, period one as second, and period two as third. This is specified in the data as they are entered, but when I run the `ggplot` bar command, `R` decides that period one is a better candidate for first position.

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_bar(data = eg_data, aes(y = trip, x = period, fill = size), 
           stat = "identity",position = 'stack')
```

First, why does `R` feel the need to display data in a manner other than how I fed it in, and second, how do I correct this IE specify which groupings I want and in what order.

All help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can create the column as a `factor` with `levels` specified as the `unique` values of that column.  With that, the values are not sorted and would be in the same order as in the order of sequence of occurrence of the first `unique` value of 'period'

```
library(tidyverse)
eg_data %>%
   mutate(period = factor(period, levels = unique(period))) %>% 
   ggplot() +
      geom_bar(aes(y = trip, x = period, fill = size),  
            stat="identity",position='stack')
```

[image]

EDIT - solution with baseR would be as follows -

```
eg_data$period <- factor(eg_data$period, levels = c("1 & 2", "1", "2"))
```

Comment: This works, thank you. Question, though - they are factors by default with the data I have...why does R feel the need to sort them into an order other than the order in which I enter them? I thought this might be the case, so I changed the variable type to character, but the got the same result...if they are character, I'd think there is no sorting going on at all, yet...it still seems to sort. Can someone explain why?

Comment: @Adam_S  If you have `factor` class columns by default, check the `levels`, it would be `1, 1&2, 2`.  Based on that levels, the ordering happens

Comment: Helpful, again. I didn't know I could check the levels, thank you. Question still remains...I enter them in an order, why does R disrupt that order when I do not  explicitly request it?

Comment: @Adam_S   Let's say you have two vectors `v1 <- factor(c("C", "A", "B", "1&2", "24")); v2 <- factor(c("24", "A", "B", "C", "1&2"))`  Here, we didn't specify any order. the levels are picked up in alphabetic order `levels(v1); levels(v2)`

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question.